# Why are my questions being deleted on ELL?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

someone told me that i can edit my previous question which is on hold ([Focused & Narrowed & Two Ships Flanking: What is happening with these two ships?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9427)), but I found that it is deleted and can't be edited, so I ask my new question, but I don't like my this question because of no picture and other things, but I think my new question will be on hold again for duplicate or something, will it? or just shall I repost again with picture and less other things? oh, hold on, at the  first time, my question is on hold and deleted; at the second time, someone tell me that I should edit the first question, but the first question is deleted, and the second question is deleted again, so what happened?

@WendiKidd @J.R. , Im a llitle confused now: my first question is : https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9427/focused-narrowed-two-ships-flanking-what-is-happening-with-these-two-ships , and my second question is : https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9491/focused-and-narrowed  and Matt edited my third different question: [Distorted Cabin & Oily Sheen: What is going on in this paragraph?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/distorted-cabin-oily-sheen-what-is-going-on-in-this-paragraph)  --so the same question are deleted.anyway, maybe let it go, but i hope people can add picture to their questions here.

Comment: I don't understand why you've asked this question so many times.  You already got satisfactory answers from several different people.  You aren't going to learn anything new by asking it again.

Comment: how do you know i got satisfactory answers?... @snailboat  i dont have an answer, you see, they deleted my question, how can i got satisfactory answers ?

Comment: I know because I read them.  In particular, the answer you got on the Physics SE seemed pretty good to me.

Answer (score 9):

Just to illustrate quite how widespread your cross-posting / duplicatation of questions are, here is an incomplete list of questions you've asked in the past two days across the Stack Exchange network that are effectively duplicates of each other:

- https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9491/focused-and-narrowed
- A second time on [What does "focused and narrowed" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9507/what-does-focused-and-narrowed-mean)
- And a third time [Distorted Cabin & Oily Sheen: What is going on in this paragraph?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/distorted-cabin-oily-sheen-what-is-going-on-in-this-paragraph)
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124132/what-really-happened-when-the-ship-was-flying-from-point-a-to-point-b
- A second time on https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124135/what-happen-really-when-a-low-rumble-come
- https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/what-really-happened-when-the-ship-was-flying-from-point-a-to-point-b
- A second time on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4280/what-happen-really-when-a-low-rumble-come
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39940/what-really-happened-when-the-ship-was-flying-from-point-a-to-point-b
- And again on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39941/what-happen-really-when-a-low-rumble-come
- https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/what-really-happened-when-the-ship-was-flying-from-point-a-to-point-b
- And again on https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8716/what-happen-really-when-a-low-rumble-come
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75332/what-happen-really-when-a-low-rumble-come
- And again on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75524/the-sound-change-the-light
- https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10074/distorted-the-cabin-and-an-oily-sheen-on-the-walls-are-just-the-illusion-of

And it's not even just here that you've been abusively cross-posting the same question. You've even started asking on other sites too:

- http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130828224356AAPqJ6c

Here on the Stack Exchange network we have a rule of thumb: If you ask a question on one Stack Exchange site, and then ask the exact same question on a different Stack Exchange site, **we will close the duplicate**, regardless of whether it is on topic for the second site.

**Do not cross-post your questions within the Stack Exchange network**. It's anti-social, it's time consuming for the moderators, and it won't get you better answers.

Comment: i just wonder why some of the questions are duplicated ? because i ask physics things in physics site(even less quoting ), and english in english. can't SE change? am i running against a wall of obstinacy?

Comment: of course , i will not ask the duplicated questions which is duplicated obviously . my fault , Im sorry.

Comment: I think _obstinacy_ is a good word for it, but I'm not sure the obstinacy rests on the Stack Exchange network. Read the last paragraph of my answer again. The question wasn't appropriate for Physics because the sci-fi genre generally doesn't care much about physics (otherwise, you wouldn't _hear_ explosions in space). The question wasn't appropriate on Writers because it wasn't something you were writing. And why would biologists be interested in the oily sheen? These communities were set up for the benefit of the community, not one particular individual with a burning question.

Answer (score 8):

What happened? What happened is that you kept asking questions that were off-topic and virtual duplicates, giving the moderator team a lot of work to deal with. This wasn't a matter of too much deleting, it was a matter of too much asking.

To me, [Question 9427](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9427) and [Question 9492](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9492) seemed like duplicates; they both asked about the same passage, and they both had the same [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/906DU.jpg). Both questions were put on hold for being off-topic. I didn't see the need to keep two on-hold questions on the site, so I chose to delete one of them. I opted to delete 9427, because I thought that the stream of comments on 9492 would be more beneficial to the community in the long run. (Similarly, when dealing with duplicates [9494](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9494) and [9428](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9428), when I had to decide which one should be closed, and which one should be kept open, I decided to leave the one that had an answer open, because it would have more long-term usefulness.)

It should be noted that your first question was kept open for about a day before it was closed, and no one answered it. Moreover, you asked the [same question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124132); it stayed open for about a day before it was put on hold, and nobody answered it there, either.

When questions stay open that long, and get no answers, and then get put on hold, you shouldn't ask the question again. Instead, realize that the question is pretty much **unanswerable**. As I said in my comments, there's no way for someone to look at a sketch, and confirm that what you have drawn accurately depicts what's in a short passage from a book, particularly a science fiction book.

I'll take this opportunity to stress the [goal of Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/): to "build **libraries of high-quality questions and answers**, focused on the most important topics in each area of expertise." Members of the community are encouraged to use tools – like upvoting and downvoting, closing and editing, and moderator flags – to keep the quality of the site high, and the questions on-topic. On occasion, that means closing a question that can't be definitively answered, or closing a question that's easily answered with trivial research, or deleting a question that's already been asked by the same user.

Comment: I don't think my question is easily answered, at least for me, im not sure things sometimes... and my picture there is to help my question, i think it's free to let people decide whether to take a look at it.and someone with a picture is good, i think @WendiKidd said so, and i think so, and WendiKidd said i can edit my first question to make it reopened. if i post a question without a picture , especially without how i think about the question, and this question is welcome, i doubt .

Comment: I didn't say your question was easily answered. In fact, I said it was pretty much **unanswerable**. Yes, Wendi said you could edit your first question, but that remark was made **before** you posted your [second question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9492). If you want to make edits, work on the second one now; that's the one that hasn't been deleted, and it still has the picture.

Comment: @Lincoln In addition, I've just been informed that you asked the same question that you asked twice here and once on ELU [on Physics as well](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75332/what-happen-really-when-a-low-rumble-come). This is not how SE works. I did tell you that you could edit it, but you'll note that after the cleanup, Matt edited the second version of the question for you, to make it more understandable and in hopes you'd receive better answers. I think that was pretty nice of him. We're trying to work with you but we need some effort to follow the rules from you as well!

Comment: I think *pretty much unanswerable* pretty much sums it up. We've no reason to suppose even the original writer has any clear idea of exactly how certain things would appear in outer space (which I believe is the context). In such contexts it's really up to the reader to visualise things for himself, in whatever way enables him to get on with the story. It's not a precise description that needs to be fleshed out with diagrams, where we could all agree on *exactly* how it would look if the scenario were to actually occur.

Comment: @WendiKidd , Im a llitle confused now: my first question is : http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9427/focused-narrowed-two-ships-flanking-what-is-happening-with-these-two-ships , and my second question is : http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9491/focused-and-narrowed  and Matt edited my third different question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/distorted-cabin-oily-sheen-what-is-going-on-in-this-paragraph  --so the same question are deleted.anyway, maybe let it go, but i hope people can add picture to their questions here.

Comment: @WendiKidd i just wonder why  the questions are duplicated ? because i ask physics things in physics site(even less quoting ), and english in english. can't SE change? am i running against a wall of obstinacy?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I hope people say that what's wrong with my picture , it's ok too. and i hope people say that what's wrong with the physics principle in the text , too , of course to ask in physics site , i mean.

Comment: @WendiKidd and could i ask a duplicated question (http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/distorted-cabin-oily-sheen-what-is-going-on-in-this-paragraph) in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/ , because i don't think the answer is very right...  no special cases in SE?

Comment: If you don't think an answer is correct, **don't** ask another question. Leave a POLITE comment explaining why you're not 100% satisfied, and **let others have a turn at answering the question**. Be patient. As for why the questions are duplicates, they are duplicates when you ask them on the same exchange. So, your FIRST question on Physics was closed because it was OFF-TOPIC, and your SECOND question on Physics was closed because it was a duplicate of the first. **Know the [AUDIENCE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/about) of each site before you post a question**.

Comment: Even here in the comments, you are exhibiting the same behavior. You asked the same question in comments on my answer as you did in comments in Matt's answer. You are coming across as a small child jumping up and down and demanding attention. Lastly, this is an English forum. Stop typing "i hope" and "i mean" and "i ask". The first person pronoun is typed in upper case, as in: _I hope I won't see anymore of that_.

Comment: I  didn't notice this comment... I just not used to press the "Caps Lock" button , it takes more time, probably a non English speaker didn't do well in the beginning ,and then "not used to". OK, I try it. @J.R.